# Collision Detection Beyond an Intersection Test

Tags: testing, 2d, collision-detection, intersection

To clarify the purpose of this, imagine a 2-dimentional game in which the player controls a small sprite which can be given an arbitrary velocity. It is acted on by gravity only. It rests initially on a large platform spanning the majority of the bottom of the screen, and a small distance above it is another, much smaller platform. If the sprite jumps straight up, it'll be able to pass up through the bottom of the platform, travel above it for a bit, then come down and land on top of the upper platform. It can pass up through the bottom, but can't go down through the top.

It's possible to do this by viewing each of the solid edges of the objects on screen as a vector that can be passed through from the right, left, or both; in the example, you'd need one edge for the top of the main base platform (if it pointed from the right corner to the left corner, it would be impermeable from the right), another for the smaller platform's top, and several more for the sprite (four, if it was a small rectangle). If a point passes through the edge from the wrong way, it sends a signal to a collision resolution algorithm which makes sure the point doesn't do that.

It all works wonderfully, the only problem is that it's not very efficient. Using traditional collision detection mechanisms, a square is one object. If you have a list of *n* squares to test collisions between, you have to run--at most; most methods shrink this number--*n* squared collision tests. Using the point-edge method, each square has about four edges, each of which has two endpoints to be tested. That means for *n* squares, you'll run about (8*n*) squared collision tests. 64 times as many collision tests; that's terrible.

So, pretty much, are there any widely-used or more accepted collision detection methods that will accomplish the same thing as the point-edge method, but will not overly burden the processing power of the computer? Take note that this is only really applicable in 2D; it's meant to let things layer to represent a sort of in-axis, whereas 3D is fully capable of representing all three dimensions of space and needn't be augmented.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done using a quad-tree of bounding boxes. Each node of the tree has bounds that enclose its immediate children. For *n* nodes you will need at most *k log*( *n* ) comparisons. It's a binary search in two dimensions.

Note the bounding boxes do not necessarily correspond exactly to your squares. They are grid aligned for cheap hit testing by range comparison.

Once you have a hit on the bounding box of one of your atoms, do a full hit test on the atom.

This approach is most often used in conjunction with polygon hit testing, which is quite expensive for polygons with many sides (don't call them complex polygons, a complex polygon is one that is "twisted" with intersecting sides).